# Print to default printer without open the printer confirmation dialog box in html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

In html file print the particular div on clicking the button without open the printer confirmation popup dialog box automatically print that content.

Comment: Remember, the machine you are asking to print on is not yours, it's mine. Therefore you cannot print on my PC unless I say it's Ok to print. Therefore you cannot circumvent the dialog that appears on my PC

Answer (score 1):

This it not practically possible in a way that's supported by all *modern* browsers. And for good reason.

You don't want random websites to start printing stuff without your intervention.

Comment: Is there any other possiblities to bypass that popup box?

Comment: No there isn't a way to bypass the popup box

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the google chrome shortcut in the desktop,Select PROPERTIES
Then
in Target

Add the given code at the end

--user-data-dir=c:\tmp  --kiosk-printing

For example:

"C:\Users\alpha\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=c:\tmp  --kiosk-printing.

It's useful for instant billing using the normal window.print option without any popup box interfere.

Comment: This may work for you to print on your PC. But it wont work anywhere else because you cannot come round to my house and make me, make these amendments to my browser

Comment: Why vote down? This could be viable solution for some of us. TS didn't specify whether the solution should be able to run on all PC or all browser. Sometimes we just need to make it run on 1 single PC. It's ok if we need to pre-config the windows to allow whatsoever security concern.